# Gridview- 2 SQL sources, adding and editing

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, gridview

Im trying to accomplish the following with a gridview control and two sql data sources:

- Load SQL data from one db into gridview
- Have a line to add data into a different SQL DB
- (tricky part) If someone was to edit the data, have the gridview loaded with the original info from DB#1, then the add/edit line auto-populated with the added data from DB#2

I've been looking into this for ages but cant seem to find a proper solution. Hopefully my explanation makes sense. If its foolish, and theres a much better route to take I would love to hear some suggestions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind a control to two data sources. Gather the data first and populate an in-memory store with it - then bind to the in-memory store, such as a DataSet/DataTable.